# How to navigate to the parent Vue component in WebStorm in a Vue3 project using Composition API style

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, webstorm, vue-composition-api

Since migrating to Vue3 and adopting the Composition API style, there's one small thing I miss from developing in the previous pattern now called the Options API style. When editing a component in WebStorm/IntelliJ IDE, you used to be able to command-click (Mac) on the "export" keyword and it would jump to the parent component, or show a list of imports/usages.

For example, this password reset component is included in the Login page, so clicking its export easily takes you there.

[image]

Now the Composition API style using a setup script does away with an explicit export, so I can't find anything to click!

I know I can use <kbd>Alt+F7</kbd> on the file to find file-references, but this isn't as elegant as I have to first go to the file-panel then it loads up the file-search panel which I then have to review, click and dismiss. Also it's not TS/JS-module oriented, but file-oriented so doesn't always give the same results.

It's only a tiny omission but something I realise I used constantly, and this is really slowing down my workflow.

Answer (score 1):

A method I have noticed which will work for some components is to click a property definition within `defineProps()` which pops up the usages panel for the property including both references in the template plus where it's set in the parent(s).
[image]

It doesn't work quite perfectly:

- the ($) button to remove "this" references doesn't remove the current component, as one might expect.
- the parent usage setting the prop should be detected as a "Write Access" but every usage is listed as "Read"
- the "dynamic uses" option picks up unrelated but same-words, and also seemed to reference generated code (like JS from TS) so I turned that off.

So you can't seem to do "only calling references" and you can't use it if don't have any properties defined.